# Oracle APex Classic Report Row Template with rowspan

Tags: oracle-apex

Merge Cells Required in Classic report Similar as in this example

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100309:39:1817309967760::NO:::

[Merge cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e8a1.png)

Kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

1. On *Rendering* panel, go to your report's attributes:

   [image]
2. Scroll down until section "**Break Formatting**", in break column attribute select the option that fits you the most. Example: if you select "**First Column**" then the first column in your report will be "merged" grouping all similar values. If you select "**First and second columns**" then the same thing will happen but it will also group similar values for the second column.

[image]

Comment: Hey kindly see above merge cell image. if you have merge row solution then reply me otherwise don't answer here